# React Native Expo app's login feature not working in production .apk

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a React Native Expo app that includes a login feature. While this login functionality works perfectly during development, it fails to operate as expected in the production .apk.

Here is my eas.json configuration:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.1.0"
  },

  "production": {
    "android": {
      "buildType": "apk"
    }
  }
}
```

I changed login component but nothing helped.